# how to connect database to c# software

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to connect a sql server database to c# form application , but there is a problem faced me in the code of connection , i created a button on the form and the following code is the code of this button :

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     string conString = "Data Source= 
    (LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: /Users/Youssef 
    Salah/Documents/koko.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

        con.Open(); // that line \\

        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            string q = " INSERT INTO Users(ID_User,Name , Email_Address , 
                passwordd) VALUES (3 ,'koko' , 'yoyo' , 'lala')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
        }
        con.Close();

  }
```

the problem is in the line ( con.Open(); ) it is supposed to open the connection but it seems that the compiler does not read this line ,because the lines which inside the if statement can not executed , the program dose not print the Done! message or show the MessageBox

Comment: The debugger is your friend.  Put a stop line on this click event and when you press the button, the code will stop there.  Then go through your code line by line to see what it does.

Comment: Also use exception handling to see any errors.

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: (LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB is for MS SQL LocalDB 2014. Check if you're using LocalDB or not and the version is 2014. It seems the key is connectionstring.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, the white space in your connection string may be causing problems, and you don't have any exception handling to see what error is occuring.  Try this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
       string conString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Youssef Salah\Documents\koko.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

       con.Open(); // that line \\

       if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Done!");
           string q = " INSERT INTO Users(ID_User,Name , Email_Address , passwordd) VALUES (3 ,'koko' , 'yoyo' , 'lala')";

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
       }
       con.Close();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Notice that I have added exception handling (`try...catch`) which will display the error message if one happens; and I have cleaned up your connection string to use backslashes in the path name (prefixing the string with `@` so that the backslashes are compiled as literal backslashes rather than escape characters) and removed the new line and other whitespace characters within your connection string that were likely causing it to refer to an invalid file name.